# Best Practice for get specific image on multi file attachments in Octobercms

Tags: php, octobercms

**my system;**

I use my octobercms website as a service for my mobile app. Mobile users take multiple photos and save them on their own account. For this, I associate each user with their photos with "file attachments relationship" in the my user model.

```php
public $attachMany = [
    'photos' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

---

**when they(users) want to update one of the photos;**

I loop all the photos of that user. If I understand that the picture is the correct one using the if condition, I am changing it.

```php
foreach ($model->photos as $photo) {
    if ( is $photo correct photo ) {
       // update process
    }
}
```

---

**my question**

To avoid looping all images with foreach;

Is there a method like adding a key during saving process and then taking the photo with that key? **Or what is the best practice of this process.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply utilize `image ID` for that. when you make `attachMany` relation and if you do `$model->photos` it will return you a `collection of items(files)` with its `id`. please check attached screenshot.

[image]

> Now, when you `show images` to your phone app `you can also attach that key (ID) to images` and `when user change image, with image data you can send image ID too`

```php
// on server side now you can simply find that image using
$photo = $model->photos()->find(<<-ID->>);
if($photo) {
    // if we have $photo then its correct one
    // now, update $photo
}
else { // wrong photo id for that user }
```

> **Note:** please do not go directly like `System\Models\File::find(ID)` as it will allow user to update any image. `$model->photos()->find(ID)` ensures that `photo of that $model(user) is only accessible`.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have pointed very nicely to a point I cannot see.

Comment: i am glade it can help you :)